# Html.Raw renders ignores Div Css in Razor

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller

I am creating a news site where I would have to quickly upload news pieces. The form contains a 'textarea' where I would use Html tags to quickly format the paragraphs as required and upload it.

Later in the Details page it would show all the information as it is.

I am using '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.News.Description))' to achieve that.

```
<div class="news-details">
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.AddNews.Description))
</div>
```

It's working out okay except that it seems to ignore the Css width (or in fact the whole css) of the parent Div. From what I can understand, since I am using Layout page and Html.Raw renders it even before 'RenderBody', this problem occurs.

Please let me know:
1) If there is any workaround for the problem as it is. Or
2) If I can dump Html.Raw all together and make use of any other way to render Html in Razor
3) I need a different approach altogether.

Kindly shed light. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an example of the resulting HTML in such a div? And of the CSS for that matter.

Comment: CSS and the rendered HTML are processed on the browser, the `@html.Raw` is processed on the server. Therefore it will be the content generated produced by the `@html.Raw` that is of significance.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys.
The css from 'main-content' from Layout page is ignored and paragraph stretches horizontally across the whole page. 
Just now, I did figure a temp workaround. '$(".main-content").addClass("maincontent-fix");'
Using javascript I added a class to reinforce the css on document.ready. Its working but would need something more robust. Any ideas?